# Solving this second order differential equation $m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+c\frac{dx}{dt}+k\sin{x}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I am investigating something in Physics and found out that I will have to solve this equation:
$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+c\frac{dx}{dt}+k\sin{x}=0$$

I haven't even learned how to solve ones that involve $kx$ and so I am very troubled by the $k\sin{x}$. Is this possible to solve? If so how could it be solved for $x$?

---

Edit: I can't assume that $\sin{x}\approx x$ since I am investigating cases in which such an assumption is not applicable (at large angles of $x$)

Comment: can you assume that $$\sin(x)\approx x$$?

Comment: The thing I'm investigating for Physics is when the small angle approximation does not apply and so I cannot make such an assumption.

Comment: then you can use a numerical method

Comment: could you elaborate? I'm only a 12th grade student so all this is new to me

Comment: Solve the equation using on a computer by approximating derivatives is what Sonnhard meant. Can I ask what the project is about, who gave you this problem etc?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations i hope this will help you

Comment: @Mattos The project is about investigation how the mass of a pendulum affects the damping of that pendulum (when experiencing air resistance). As a result, for the theoretical side, I would have to find a relationship between the displacement of the pendulum bob over time and the mass of the bob. I know that investigating this with smaller angles (around 10º) would allow me to make the small angle approx, but I want to leave this as a last resort since I still am curious about larger angles.

Comment: I doubt there's a closed-form solution (maybe something very nasty involving elliptic integrals). For the case $m = c = k = 1$, WolframAlpha provides some plots but no solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+f%27%27+%2B+f%27+%2B+sin+f+%3D+0

Comment: @DanSkyler I can give you code that you can play around with (written in Python though) if you would like to see how the solution behaves while increasing $m$ and damping parameter $c$.

Comment: @ConnorHarris, I've been having a hard time getting an implicit form involving an integral because of the $x'(t)$ term.

Comment: How familiar are you with linear algebra? It can be very helpful in analyzing such problems.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to solve this one exactly. However, I can help you with the undamped case, that is $c=0$. In this case, using $\gamma=k/m$, the equation reads
$$y''(x)=-\gamma\sin{y(x)}$$
Which is a 1D sine-Gordon equation. Multiplying by $y'(x)$ and integrating, we get the energy function
$$E=\frac{(y'(x))^{2}}{2}-\gamma\cos{y(x)}$$ 
From this,
$$y'(x)=\pm\sqrt{2(E+\gamma\cos{y(x)})}$$
Which leads to
$$x-x_{0}=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\int^{y(x)}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\gamma}{E}\cos{z}}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2E}{E^{2}+\gamma^{2}}}\mathcal{F}\Big{(}\frac{y(x)}{2}\Big{|}\frac{2\gamma}{E+\gamma}\Big{)}$$
Where $\mathcal{F}(z|k)$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind. Now, we can use a "physicist's" style first order perturbation theory in $c$, to account for finite, but very small damping we assume $c\ll 1$. Let $y(x)=y_{0}(x)+cy_{1}(x)$
Then
$$\sin{y(x)}\approx\sin{y_{0}(x)}+cy_{1}(x)\cos{y_{0}(x)}$$
And the equations for the functions are
$$my_{0}''(x)+k\sin{y_{0}(x)}=0$$
$$my_{1}''(x)+y_{0}'(x)+ky_{1}(x)\cos{y_{0}(x)}=0$$
The solution to the first equation we already know. The second equation is linear second order ode, which no one knows how to solve, unfortunately.